# Maximum interval of a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my lecture note there is an ODE:

> $x' = x^2$ with initial value $x(0) = x_0$
>
> with solution:
>
> $x = \cfrac{1}{1/x_0 - t} = \cfrac{x_0}{1-x_0 t}$

The notes then say that for $x_0 > 0$, the solution exists for all $t$ in $(-\infty, 1/x_0)$ and for $x_0 < 0$, the solution exists for all $t$ in $(1/x_0, \infty)$

I'm struggling to understand why the solution exists in such a way. I can see why the solution is undefined at the point $1/x_0$ but I can't see why it cannot exceed $1/x_0$ for example when $x_0 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of solution includes the differential equation *and* the initial value. There is no continuously differentiable function $x\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ where $a<0<b$ and $b>x_0$ satisfying the two conditions

1. $x'=x^2$ and
2. $x(0)=x_0$.

The function $x_0/(1-x_0t)$ is certainly a solution of the differential equation defined on $(x_0,\infty)$, but id does not satisfy the initial condition at $t=0$; it is not defined there.

Comment: That comes with the explicit solution. If $x_0>0$ then $1/x_0>0$ and the solution is defined on $(-\infty,1/x_0)$. If $x_0<0$ then $1/X_0<0$ and the solution is defined on $(1/X_0,\infty)$.

Comment: Is that because it is the maximum interval?

Comment: Because te slution is not defined at $t=1/x_0$.